# Kde no sound from Phonon or most KDE apps but mplayer,skype and firefox are ok

Tags: audio, kde, gentoo, kde-4

Can somebody tell me why I cannot get any sound with *most* of KDE 4?

I'm running a Gentoo box,  I'm in both the 'audio' and 'video' groups.  I can get sound with mplayer ( but not smplayer ) Firefox and Skype but nothing else.  I can't get the test sound to play from the settings window,  but Phonon is not whining about broken sound cards when I start up.

I have checked with kmix, we seem to be completely unmuted ( and I can get sound with some apps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try going to the **Backend** tab and see which is the top preferred selection, and perhaps change it to prefer one over the other. For good measure may as well re-compile **media-sound/phonon** and all it's audio-related deps while you're at it.

All those other apps don't give a hoot about Phonon, so that's why they work.

For reference, I also run a Gentoo desktop w/ KDE4 (4.3.4) and set xine as my preferred backend with GStreamer as second. I never had a problem with mine, and have been *"emerge -uD world*"-ing since 2008.0

Comment: Sadly, that's not the answer. It might have been the answer for someone else... :-)

Comment: try using phonon-mplayer (mplayer backedn for phonon).
maybe it works.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the `~/.pulse` and `~/.pulse-cookie` files fixed this mess for me.

Opening `System Settings -> Multimedia` recreated them, so I suppose the older ones were messed up after an upgrade of the KDE/Qt packages.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue is a combination of suck: phonon and pulseaudio. Try deleting the pulseaudio settings in your home dir. Maybe reboot. I forget what happened to fix it but I haven't been having the problem too much lately. However I still get errors like that every once in awhile. I use Debian/Lenny and Ubuntu 9.10.

Maybe someday Linux will get a stable sound system. One would think that it would be a solved problem by now...